# load balancer on kubernetes with dynamic config

Tags: nginx, haproxy

Need to use a load balancer(with ingress on bare metals) in kubernetes which can help me with

- Domain names : Auto update ssl Certificates : letsencrypt
- Auto refresh the domain mappings :  ex.add on runtime; on running load balancer Abc.com points to service a:
- No restart required : Domain add has to be restart free

Can consider ha/nginx/traefik. Community edition.  Currently have haproxy config without the above features.

Comment: wondering what's the problem with restarts. talking about haproxy: although you can dinamically add a domain if using acls with map, currently you cannot dinamically add a backend.

Comment: can you plese give links for references in kubernetes for "acls on map" and currently my "pod are using hostpath on a given machine .. how do i dynamically reload config"

Comment: acls with map is a haproxy ref: converter doc [here](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.2/configuration.html#7.3.1-map)] and dynamic update doc [here](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.2/management.html#9.3-set%20map).